# When I remove elements from my .storyboard they're still in my app?

Tags: ios, storyboard

In the main view controller of my application I added three labels, but now I want to remove them, and with no reason, when I remove them from the .storyboard they're still in my application. 
I have no idea of what is wrong, these labels were only added with the .storyboard and not in my code.

Thanks for your advices...

Comment: Have you tried doing a "Clean" before your build?

Comment: I just tried but still having this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to remove MainStoryboard from your app then add it again to the files.

Comment: I had a similar problem, steps to do this are in my answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11531955/743

Answer (score 1):

Perform a full clean by pressing Command+Shift+K

then try deleting your app from the simulator then run it again

Comment: I have this error now (can't run the simulator) :  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle

Comment: did you delete your MainStoryboard ?