# Storyboard Device-Specific Resources

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have two storyboards named `HomeView~iphone.storyboard` and `HomeView~ipad.storyboard`. Both storyboards have an `initialViewController` in the storyboard file.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"HomeView"
                                                     bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

I get the following error when I try to access the `instantiateInitialViewController`.

> Could not find a storyboard named `HomeView` in bundle `NSBundle - NSInvalidArgumentException`

Do you have any Idea? The apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH1-SW2) says ~iphone and ~ipad is supported for any file in the bundle.

Comment: Have you tried any of the steps from this [previous SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531955/xcode-deployment-error-nsinvalidargumentexception-could-not-find-a-storyboar)? The error messages are similar.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `HomeView.storyboard` for iPhone and `HomeView~ipad.storyboard` for iPad?