# Exception while running the app for the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am getting the following exception

> 2017-06-13 10:55:13.656 myappname[11235:3769332] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could
>   not find a storyboard named 'Main~ipad' in bundle NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x24fcb91b 0x24766e17 0x29c4bf71 0x297e82ab 0x295bb445 0x297e714b 0x297fb83d 0x297e47b3 0x2666ec07
>   0x2666eab9 0x2666edb9 0x24f8ddff 0x24f8d9ed 0x24f8bd5b 0x24edb229
>   0x24edb015 0x295b4c3d 0x295af189 0x140a2d 0x24b83873) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

when I run my app for the first time in iPad and when I run the same code again the code is working fine. I have 2 different storyboard for iPhone and iPad the Main~ipad file is there in app bundle and I see the file in copy bundle resources. Please help me to fix this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode deployment error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531955/xcode-deployment-error-nsinvalidargumentexception-could-not-find-a-storyboar)

Comment: Have you added Main storyboard file base name in Plist for the ipad Storyboard ?

Comment: I have added Main storyboard file base name = Main & Main storyboard file base name (iPad) = Main~ipad @AravindAR

Comment: if you are init any framework in appdelegate. then comment it and try it once. in my case it was facebook sdk and fabric

Comment: @vivekpadaya I am using Braintree SDK and the frameworks related to it

Comment: is your app still crashing after comment it?

Comment: Now it is not crashing But I need that SDK in my code

Comment: Try to re-install it.

Comment: @vivekpadaya I re install using cocoa pods still its happening

Comment: Try to run your project in new xcode version